# Is a safe accumulator really this complicated?

Tags: c++, c, undefined-behavior, integer-overflow

I'm trying to write an accumulator that is well behaved given unconstrained inputs. This seems to not be trivial and requires some pretty strict planning. Is it really this hard?

```
int naive_accumulator(unsigned int max,
                      unsigned int *accumulator,
                      unsigned int amount) {
    if(*accumulator + amount >= max) {
        return 1; // could overflow
    }

    *accumulator += max; // could overflow

    return 0;
}

int safe_accumulator(unsigned int max,
                     unsigned int *accumulator,
                     unsigned int amount) {
    // if amount >= max, then certainly *accumulator + amount >= max
    if(amount >= max) {
        return 1;
    }

    // based on the comparison above, max - amount is defined
    // but *accumulator + amount might not be
    if(*accumulator >= max - amount) {
        return 1;
    }

    // based on the comparison above, *accumulator + amount is defined
    // and *accumulator + amount < max
    *accumulator += amount;

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: I have removed the style bias

Comment: The "complicated" version is 1 more line of code than the "simple" version (if you used the same style conventions for *safe* as you used for *naive*), that doesn't seem too "hard" ...

Comment: Throw an exception (or whatever) if the difference between the accumulated value and the max is greater than the new value.

Comment: A) Why not pass by reference instead of using a pointer? and B) Why not use an or (`||`) and take advantage of short circuiting to make the `safe_accumulator` the same number of lines as the `naive_accumulator`?

Comment: Overflow in the CPU is indicated by a single bit *outside* of the actual registers. So technically, overflow is tested through performing the addition with slightly larger registers, and you cannot say anything about the result until you check the Overflow bit. In your case a simple promotion to `unsigned long` would do.

Comment: @Jongware: well, unless `unsigned int` and `unsigned long` are the same width.

Comment: @Jongware Unless unsigned long is the same size of unsigned int.

Comment: Then, "a larger type than `unsigned int`" :-) My point is, a CPU *cheats* by using an extra bit. Hard to mimick in plain C without a promotion to a larger size.

Comment: @Jongware: C and C++ don't guarantee that there is a larger type.

Comment: Although you'd have high hopes for `unsigned long long`, even that's not actually guaranteed. An architecture on which everything (maybe except `char`) is 64 bits isn't that implausible, I suspect there have been mainframe-style machines.

Comment: http://safeint.codeplex.com/

Comment: Idea #2: testing against a numeric overflow of `unsigned int`, or testing agains some (random) `max`? The former may (I may need to think this through) return a result that is smaller than one of its inputs.

Comment: @Jongware: sure, you can detect overflow of unsigned types with `(a + b < a)`, and once you have something that works it's just a question of performance what you decide to actually use.

Comment: Your safe one isn't quite safe yet. Luckily, Matt had a good answer repairing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you considered:

```
if ( max - *accumulator < amount )
    return 1;

*accumulator += amount;
return 0;
```

By changing the direction of your first comparison in the "naive" version you avoid overflows, i.e. see how much room is left (safe) and compare that against the amount to add (also safe).

This version assumes that `*accumulator` never exceeds `max` already when the function is called; if you want to support that case then you'd have to add in an extra test.

Comment: I would like it to support the case where *accumulator is already greater than max, that is why I specified unconstrained in the question. Could you show me the version that supports unconstrained input? @Deduplicator implied that there's a mistake in mine.

Comment: @Martin add in at the start `if ( *accumulator > max ) { /* do whatever you want to do in this case */ }`

Comment: @Martin "Your extra test will never pass if max == UINT_MAX" - of course, that is intentional. If `max == UINT_MAX` then `*accumulator` cannot be greater than it.

Comment: " if max == UINT_MAX, amount == UINT_MAX and *accumulator > 0, your function will overflow" - no, it will return `1`

Comment: I have stepped through it using a debugger, you're right. I was confused, I've deleted my comment. Thank you!